# Why does this async function work when imported from source directory but not when imported from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, v8, testcafe

**Summary:** I have an async function that fails when it is imported from the `node_modules` directory but succeeds when it is imported from my source directory. I've tested this by just copy / pasting code into the `node_modules` directory.

I had always assumed that importing code from `node_modules` was exactly the same as importing from any other directory, but apparently this isn't true.

**Question:** *Why* does the below function `clickBodyTwice` work when imported from my source directory but not when imported from `node_modules`?

**Disclaimer:** The function uses the [TestCafe](https://testcafe.io/) library and makes use of [implicit test controller access](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402665/reference/test-api/testcontroller#implicit-test-controller-use). They clearly say this is not supported in an async context, and the fix is provided. My question is not how to fix this, but *why* there is a difference between importing from the two directories.

**Background:** I am attempting to export a library that uses this pattern. The devs have used it across the entire project for years. Surprisingly, it works even though TestCafe explicitly says it shouldn't. That is until you export the library and import it into `node_modules`. The fix is to pass the test controller as a parameter, but unfortunately that's going to require a lot of refactoring, and educating devs why not to use this pattern.

**click-body-twice.js**

```js
const { t } = require("testcafe");
async function clickBodyTwice() {
    console.log("begin");

    await t.click("body");
    console.log("clicked once");

    await t.click("body");
    console.log("clicked twice");
}
exports.clickBodyTwice = clickBodyTwice;
```

Here I import this function from two different places, one succeeds and one fails. The test just navigates to google and attempts to click the body twice.

**test.js**

```js
const { clickBodyTwice: topLevelFn } = require("./@@bug-repro/click-body-twice")
const { clickBodyTwice: nodeModuleFn } = require("./node_modules/@@bug-repro/click-body-twice")

fixture("Testcafe bug repro")

test("succeeds", async (t) => {
    await t.navigateTo("http://www.google.com");
    await topLevelFn();
})

test("fails", async (t) => {
    await t.navigateTo("http://www.google.com");
    await nodeModuleFn();
})
```

**package.json**

```js
{
    "dependencies": {
        "testcafe": "3.5.0"
    }
}
```

**To reproduce:**

I reproduced with Node v20.11.0 & v18.19.0

1. Copy the above code into the following file structure:

```
@@bug-repro
   - click-body-twice.js
package.json
test.js
```

2. Run `npm i`
3. Copy `@@bug-repro` into `node_modules`
4. Run `npx testcafe chrome .\test.js`

**The result:**

```
PS C:\repos\testcafe-bug> npx testcafe chrome .\test.js
 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 120.0.0.0 / Windows 10

 Testcafe bug repro
begin
clicked once
clicked twice
 √ succeeds
begin
clicked once
 × fails

   1) The action does not have implicit test controller access. Reference the 't' object to gain it.

      Browser: Chrome 120.0.0.0 / Windows 10

          3 |    console.log("begin");
          4 |
          5 |    await t.click("body");
          6 |    console.log("clicked once");
          7 |
       >  8 |    await t.click("body");
          9 |    console.log("clicked twice");
         10 |}
         11 |exports.clickBodyTwice = clickBodyTwice;
         12 |

         at clickBodyTwice (C:\repos\testcafe-bug\node_modules\@@bug-repro\click-body-twice.js:8:10)



 1/2 failed (7s)
```

Notice how the first click attempt does have access to the test controller, while the second does not. Also notice that the exact same code imported from somewhere else does not face the same issue. This leads me to believe that `await` acts differently when in the `node_modules` directory, and somehow blocks TestCafe from referencing the test controller. I'm not sure the mechanism TestCafe uses to get implicit test controller access, nor do I know why Node.js would act differently when importing code from `node_modules`. Any information would be great.

I've also reported this as a bug in the hopes I'll get an explanation: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/8121

---

**Update**

Step through debugging reveals TestCafe is using [V8's stacktrace API](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api) via the [callsite package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsite) to find the test controller.

I've stopped execution at the same point where the failure occurs, and the stack traces are different.

**From my source directory**
[image]

**From node_modules**
[image]

They've actually embedded the controller ID into a function name, and retrieve it via the stack trace. This mechanism seems to fail in the node_modules directory.

Comment: You're mixing CommonJS and ES6 module semantics, it looks like. I don't know that that would make a difference. Does the same thing happen if you do the two `imports` in the other order?

Comment: Changed to commonjs imports just in case - no change. Order of imports does not change things either. I've made an update since I've found that the stack traces are different between the two. They're naming a function with the run ID, then fetching the ID from the stack trace by getting the function name - wild.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton That looks like code in your source directory is transpiled (for `asyncGeneratorStep`, as if your runtime didn't support `async`/`await`) whereas the code in *node_modules* is not transpiled.

Comment: @Bergi interesting theory, but stopping at the first `t.click` in the `node_modules` test yields the same stack frame as the working one (including `asyncGeneratorStep`). Looks like part of the stack frame is just dropped during the second `await` in `node_modules`. Could you explain more about what would be doing the transpiling?

Comment: Well *is* your code transpiled? I mean, seems like that could make a *huge* difference.

Comment: @Pointy well it's not transpiled by me. Perhaps TestCafe is doing it though. They do have  built in Typescript transpilation so it's not off the table.

Comment: Also, the fact that the product explicitly documents that things don't work in a variety of circumstances due to the behavior of the runtime and the state of the stack, well, that says a lot.

Comment: @Pointy looks like TestCafe does do some transpilation, based on this comment: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6283#issuecomment-856613708 So I'm inclined to believe it's their compiler that has special treatment for node_modules.

Comment: I would say it is an anti-pattern to require a module by explicitly naming the `node_modules` folder.  For example, you could use yarn instead, and then you wouldn't even have a node_modules folder.  This would also confound a bundler.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the pointer. The original library is written in Typescript, so I just targeted es2015 and it transpiled away `async / await`. This fixed the issue. It makes me real worried that there will be other similar issues by having the library in node_modules. Hopefully the TestCafe devs can shed some light on why transpilation differs there.